# Logic App to check the Azure blob container for new files and send email notification

Tags: azure-logic-apps, copy-data

Im trying to achieve the following scenario and have searched the net for days and even tried to get Chat GPT to help but didnt get anywhere. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

I have two storage accounts in Azure, users will upload lots of files (number unknown).

- I want logic app to detect the change to container
- monitor it till no more files have been uploaded for 20mins.
- Then send a single approval email to manager,
- Once approved, copy the data from the source storage account to 2nd storage account.
- Once copied logic app find out which user uploaded the files
- and send them an email to say request approved and data copied.

I got most of it working except these two issues

1st issue i had was that if the user uploaded 15 files to container, then my logic app sent 15 emails to manager for approval (i want just one when upload is completed).

2nd issue is that i cant figure out how to get users email address from the blob they uploaded. i had to upload a file with the users email address in it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue, try disabling the `Split on` parameter in the trigger:

[image]

For the second issue, perhaps you can use Graph API to retrieve user's identity object, which contains the email address?

Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-use-select-to-retrieve-specific-properties-of-a-user

Comment: Hi, i tried turning off split on and it didnt work, for some strange reason, three tasks were running and i also got three approval emails for 2 uploaded files.

On the graph api, i have never used it and dont know how to use it, i'll do some reading up on that, not sure if there is any step by step guide for what im trying to do.

Comment: If turning off "Split on" doesn't help you, you can also try refactoring your solution. For example, one Logic App to send data about each added or modified blob to a Service Bus queue, and another Recurrence Logic App to process all messages accumulated in the queue.